# Reusable Goo Canisters and Jr. Science Bays

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I would like to ask, how did Scott Manley in his Interstellar quest videos, able to reset the Goo Canister and Jr Science Bay after transmitting the data and used it again? He didn't even include the Science Lab in his Probe/rover?

All I know is that after transmitting these Sciences, they will be useless.

Comment: To date there are something like 88 Scott Manley Interstellar videos totaling around 30 hours. You will be more likely to get an answer if you specify which video you are asking about.

Comment: Since I am at work, I can't really access the youtube site now and its killing me. Anyway It was during the Episode 8 of his quest titled "Munar Survey Program" at around 14:00 of his video, his rover gathered some Science then after transmitting it reset on its own. Thanks for replying

Comment: Maybe it was from the first version where the science system was introduced? Both experiments were resettable back then.

Answer (score 1):

Science Jrs and goo can be "reset". But you'll need:

1. One Kerbal to EVA with
2. One science lab (this will require 2 Kerbals to operate)

Then just follow these instructions:

1. **Make Science** - Do experiments, and click "Keep Data". Don't transmit.
2. **Collect Science** - EVA, next to your parts, click on the equipment that you kept data in and select "Collect data".
3. **Store Science** - You can take this data straight to capsule to store it in or store it in science lab, only matters if you plan to enhance data for additional transmission, its best to bring it back though. While in EVA you can click on capsule door or lab door close to you and select "Store data" to put the experiment in the capsule/lab.
4. **Clean parts** - Now that the experiments are inoperable (Goo and Sci Jr), they MUST be in the same ship as the lab, meaning you must dock the ship containing the experiments to the ship containing the lab. You can rightclick on the lab and select "Clean experiments". You may have to do this several times, as it will give up if you run out of energy, but it will restart from the % it left off from when you get more electricity.

Repeat. Profit.

You can remove the science from capsule by EVAing and right clicking the door of the capsule.

Make sure you return to Kerbin with the science.

Source: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalAcademy/comments/1wwev0/still_confused_by_science_transfer_and_scrubbing/)

---

Edit: the above may be useful for some other hapless kerbal so I'll leave it there and answer your question correctly.

Scott Manley is playing version 0.22 of KSP. This was the first version with science and some of the parts and functionality from the current version of the game simply didn't exist. One of those is pretty much all science parts. Before version 0.23 you could spam various science parts getting less and less science each time - and that's what Scott is doing.

The video in question is from November 2013 (a year ago). The game is very different from then and spamable science modules has long since been removed.

Source: [Kerwiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Science#Modules)

Comment: I think you did not understand my question? Thanks for replying. Yep I wholeheartedly knew how to reset these science experiment using the Science Lab, I've been doing that since. But this time its different. He did not have a:
1. Kerbal
2. Science Lab
3. Its a small "rover" and didn't had a Science Lab

But still was able to reset the equipments, and spamming Science in every biome/part of the Mun. Have you seen his video? I guess I should put up a link: www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNNzgJSNeBA

Comment: Wow, thanks! You've been a big help. I wonder why they removed the science spam? Well, I guess because they introduced the science Lab.

Comment: @Leify Spammable science was only around for that one release. It was the first version with science as I recall and I assume it wasn't fully developed. You can still spam science, you just have to have a science lab...